# How to set Background Color of Plot Area of Chart using openpyxl

Tags: python, charts, styling, openpyxl

I would like to change the background color of a chart, [as in this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEUxj.jpg), using openpyxl.

In a google group discussion I found the following code snippet:

```
from openpyxl.chart.shapes import GraphicalProperties 

props = GraphicalProperties(solidFill="999999") 
chart.graphical_properties = props 
chart.plot_area.graphical_properties = props
```

but it does not have any effect on the chart when saved to the excel file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This functionality was seemingly broken in a previous version of openpyxl and is fixed as of release 2.4.7. To achieve the result as illustrated in your picture you need to change the solid fill color of the `plot_area`:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.chart import BarChart
from openpyxl.chart.shapes import GraphicalProperties

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

chart = BarChart()

props = GraphicalProperties(solidFill="999999") 
chart.plot_area.graphicalProperties = props

ws.add_chart(chart, "A1")
wb.save("bar.xlsx")
```

**Please note:** the member object holding the graphical properties of `chart` is `chart.graphical_properties`, whereas in plot_area it is named `plot_area.graphicalProperties` - which is itself an alias for `plot_area.spPr`.

You need to be sure to access the proper member to create a valid data structure that does look as you expect it to in the Excel file.

Comment: Is there a way to set it as "nofill"?