# openpyxl set color of bar in bar chart

Tags: bar-chart, openpyxl

I would like to set the color of the bar in a bar chart with openpyxl. I created the following

```
data = Reference(sheet, min_col=3, min_row=6, max_col=4, max_row=10)
titles = Reference(sheet, min_col=1, min_row=6, max_row=10)
chart = BarChart3D()
chart.title = title
chart.add_data(data=data, titles_from_data=True)
chart.set_categories(titles)
```

I found here [How to set Background Color of Plot Area of Chart using openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43329669/how-to-set-background-color-of-plot-area-of-chart-using-openpyxl)
how change the background color using chart.plot_area.graphical_properties

However, I don't know to change the color of the bars.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For 2D plots I'm using `graphicalProperties.line.solidFill` and `graphicalProperties.solidFill` :

```
wb = load_workbook('data.xlsx')
ws = wb['sheet1']

chart = BarChart()
chart.type = "col"
chart.style = 10
chart.title = "Chart Title"
chart.y_axis.title = 'Y Axis'
chart.x_axis.title = 'X Axis'

data = Reference(ws, min_col=3, min_row=1, max_row=3, max_col=3)
cats = Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row=2, max_row=3)

chart.add_data(data, titles_from_data=True)
chart.set_categories(cats)
chart.shape = 4

# Change bar filling and line color 
s = chart.series[0]
s.graphicalProperties.line.solidFill = "00000"
s.graphicalProperties.solidFill = "ff9900" 


ws.add_chart(chart, "A10")
wb.save("bar.xlsx")
```

I hope it's the same for 3D plots

Comment: yes, it works. Ideally, I would like to have custom colors different for each column though, while now they all have the same color.

Comment: @Nicolas thank you. Is there a way to make an area chart transparent? Could you reply to my latest post? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I changed the `one_color` chart to a `multiple_color` chart with the attribute of the `chart.varyColors`:

```
chart.varyColors = "0000FFFF"
```

The string `"0000FFFF"` its the color value in the module openpyxl, you can choose your own
https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/styles.html#colours

Answer (score 1):

If you want each bar to have it's own color like you mentioned in the reply to Nicolas's answer.

```
slices = [DataPoint(idx=i) for i in range(3)]
sliceOne, sliceTwo, sliceThree = slices
sliceOne.graphicalProperties.solidFill = "02c212"
sliceTwo.graphicalProperties.solidFill = "d62b00"
sliceThree.graphicalProperties.solidFill = "f5ad31"
chart.series[0].data_points = slices
```

I understand I'm 5 years too late but in case someone else needs it.

Comment: still useful! thanks for the tip.